# Create a room system with different instances of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I created a video game based on node.js and socket.io. For now, there is only one "room" where all players can play together. Now I would like to create a room system.

But the server code is quite complex, and changing it to handle different game states would be difficult.

So I thought that maybe I can launch several instances of node on my server, and say that every room connects to a different instance.

Is it feasible? Is it recommended, and do you have other ideas?

Comment: When you say multiple instances, what exactly are you referring to?  The whole application that you've built?

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to do the whole application, you won't be able to rebind ports that are already in use, plus you're likely to face scaling issues quicker than if you were to refactor the code to account for multiple instances instead.